# Remove a single space from a string

Tags: c#

```
"How do I do this?              "
```

Let's say I have this string. How do I remove only one space from the end? The code shown below gives me an error saying the count is out of range.

```
string s = "How do I do this?              ";
s = s.Remove(s.Length, 1);
```

Comment: Array indexes (and therefore indexing a string) are 0 based in c#, so `s.Length` refers to a position that's 1 more than the maximum index of the array. Use `s.Length - 1`

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer as I think that other answers are better but the obligatory linq .... `s = s.Take(s.Length - 1).ToString();`

Comment: Side-Note: You don't need the second parameter if you want to remove to the end.

Comment: @Sayse That won't do what you think it does. Something like `new string(s.Take(s.Length - 1).ToArray())` would work (but it's not really a good idea)

Comment: @hvd - I know its not but its not a SO question without a Linq answer :P (most of the time), I didn't bother to test it so yeah your version probably does what I was expecting

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use this instead :

```
string s = "How do I do this?              ";
s = s.Remove(s.Length-1, 1);
```

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx):

> Remove(Int32) Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current
> instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the
> last position, have been deleted.

In an array, positions range from 0 to Length-1, hence the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

The indexing in C# are zero-based.

```
s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a substring from the first character (chars are 0-based in string) and get number of chars less the string length by 1

```
s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Btw, this is what `string.Remove(s.Length-1)` internally uses, but only if you use the [overload with a single parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx) `startIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little safer, just in case the last character is not a space

```
string s = "How do I do this?              ";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @" $", "")
```

Comment: If the whole point of using a regex is to avoid replacing characters that aren't a space, why does your regex match characters other than space?

Comment: Regex is very much overkill here and probably inefficient

Comment: @hvd it matches a single space followed by a line end, perhaps you are thinking of `\S` which matches a non whitespace character

Comment: @RobertByrne No, that's not what I'm thinking of. I mean `\s` matches any white-space character, not just space.

Comment: @Sayse I've never found simple a regex to be a performance issue in the grand scheme of things, but it all depends on the use case to be fair

Comment: @hvd true, you could match for the \u0020 char to leave other ws alone

Comment: @RobertByrne Or just put a literal space in the string, like so: `" $"` :)

Comment: @hvd doh! that would be easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write something in the lines of

```
string s = "How do I do this?
s = s.Remove(s.Length-1, 1);
```

Reason being that in C# when referring to indexes in arrays the first element is always at position 0 and end at Length - 1. The Length generally tells you how long a string is but doesn't map to the actual array index.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is;

```
string s = "How do I do this?              ";
s=s.SubString(0,s.Length-1);
```

**Additional :**

If you would like do some additional checking for the last character being a space or anything,you can do it in this way;

```
    string s = "How do I do this?              a";//Just for example,i've added a 'a' at the end.
    int index = s.Length - 1;//Get last Char index.
    if (index > 0)//If index exists.
    {
        if (s[index] == ' ')//If the character at 'index' is a space.
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Its a space.");
        }
        else if (char.IsLetter(s[index]))//If the character at 'index' is a letter.
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Its a letter.");
        }
        else if(char.IsDigit(s[index]))//If the character at 'index' is a digit.
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Its a digit.");
        }
    }
```

> This gives you a MessageBox with message "Its a letter".

One more thing that might be helpful,if you want to create a string with equal no. of spaces between each word,then you can try this.

```
    string s = "How do I do this?              ";
    string[] words = s.Split(new char[] {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);//Break the string into individual words.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string word in words)//Iterate through each word.
    {
        sb.Append(word);//Append the word.
        sb.Append(" ");//Append a single space.
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());//Resultant string 'sb.ToString()'.
```

> This gives you "How do I do this? " (equal spaces between words).